# Why do I keep getting a linker error even after compiling my header file?

Tags: c, header, linker-errors

I keep getting this error when compiling!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_lex", referenced from:
      _main in main-7a45f7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am compiling a file `main.c`. Here are the first few lines of the program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lex.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
```

I thought compiling the header file `"lex.h"` might have been the issue, but I was apparently wrong. I ran the command

```
gcc -c lex.c lex.o
```

and received the following warning (but no errors):

```
clang: warning: lex.o: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

I think I have included all the information needed, but these are the files in my current directory (as per `ls`):

```
lex.c  lex.h  lex.o  main.c
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you link lex.o and main.o?

Comment: This command:  `gcc -c lex.c lex.o` should just be `gcc -c lex.c`.  It doesn't know what to do with `lex.o` since you aren't producing an executable

Comment: When linking with `main.o` to produce an executable, *that's* when you need to include `lex.o` in the command, e.g. `gcc main.o lex.o -o main`.

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko I didn't realize that the main file had to be compiled into an object file. Thanks!

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, that seemed to do it. I haven't been able to find a tutorial that teaches header file compilation, so I wasn't quite sure how to do this. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5460719/tom-karzes) and [Itagaki Fumihiko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15821526/itagaki-fumihiko) for help. The fatal flaw in my compilation was not linking `main.o` and `lex.o`. To compile the files properly, **this** is what you should actually do:

```
gcc -c lex.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o lex.o
```